# Comparison of double and float - Implicit casting

Tags: c, casting

Assume we have the variables `double d` and `float f` in the C programming language.

As far as I understand the expression `d == (float) d` will not be true for all double values since when we cast it to float we truncate it and hence loose precision.

On the other hand `f == (double) f` should be true for all float values (except for NaN, because it NaN != NaN) since we aren't loosing anything (just extending the mantissa with zeros).

I have read that when comparing a float to a double the float will implicitly be cast to a double: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions, is this implicit casting correct for all values (including infinity and NaN)?

I am aware that this is a pretty straightforward question; I have played with it for a while, but it would be great if someone could confirm this. The first part is already answered in other posts, but I haven't found answers for the second part of the question.

Comment: If you look at the definitions of `INFINITY` and `NAN` in `math.h` you may see that they're specified to have `float` precision.  For example: `#define NAN (0.0F/0.0F)`, `#define INFINITY (HUGE_VALF)`, `#define HUGE_VALF (1.0e999999999F)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a C implementation that conforms to the C standard, `f == (double) f` evaluates to true for all `float` values of `f` other than NaNs. (For a NaN, `f == f` is false.) This is true because, in `f == (double) f`, the left operand is a `float`, so it is automatically converted to `double`, and the expression is then equivalent to `(double) f == (double) f`, and so is inherently true.

The C standard allows implementations to evaluate floating-point expressions with more precision than the nominal types of the operands. However, excess precision would have no effect on cast operators (which are required to discard excess precision) or the `==` operator. So `(double) f == (double) f` is not affected by this, and its computed value is the same as its mathematical value.

You might be interested in the result of `f == (float) (double) f`. In this, since both operands of `==` have type `float`, there is no automatic conversion to `double`. You could ask whether the cast conversion to `double` introduces some change, and then converting back to `float` could produce a different value. It cannot.

To see that it cannot, consider if `f` is infinity. Then `(double) f` is infinity, and so is `(float) (double) f`, so the result is a comparison of infinity to infinity, which evaluates to true. (This also holds for negative infinity.) If `f` is not infinity or a NaN, it is a finite value.

Per C 2018 6.2.5 10, “The set of values of the type `float` is a subset of the set of values of the type `double`;…” Therefore, every value representable in `float` is representable in `double`, so the conversion to `double` does not change the value, and neither does the conversion back to `float`. Therefore, `f == (float) (double) f` evaluates to true for all `float` values of `f` other than NaN.

Note that while you cannot determine whether two NaNs are identical using `==`, you could compare the bytes in their representations using `memcmp`. In this case, conversion to `double` and back to `float` is not required to preserve any information in the NaN object other than that it is a NaN; any payload information may be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Casting to a greater precision will not produce incorrect values, and it is true that comparing a `float` to a `double` will implicitly cast the `float` into a `double`.